# "The underlying connection was closed" when downloading a file from a ftp server

Tags: c#

I want to download file from the ftp server.
I have written following code to download file from ftp

```
public void downloadFile(string FTPAddress, string filename, string username, string password, string destFile)
{
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + filename) as FtpWebRequest;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false; //close the connection when done
        request.Timeout = 60000;
        //Streams
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {

            using (Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                using (Stream streamFile = File.Create(destFile))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (bytesRead == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            streamFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);             
    }
}
```

But when running this code giving me exception :

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

What can be problem help me...

Comment: When the KeepAlive property is set to false, the control connection is closed when you call the Close method.

On which line you get this exception? Did you try to use the default value of the Timeout property (Infinity) ?

Comment: Maybe it's a firewall issue. Have you tried using active instead of passive mode?

Comment: This is a problem with your server or local tcp/ip issues (firewall, antivirus, etc.). The code works fine, for example this does create a ccrisconv.txt file on my disk: `downloadFile("ftp://ftp.nlm.nih.gov/", "nlmdata/sample/ccris/ccrisconv.txt", null, null, "ccrisconv.txt");`

Comment: @Ofiris The default timeout is not infinte - http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2012/04/06/damn-the-documentation-ftpwebrequest-timeout-default-value-is-not-infinite/

Comment: Have you tried FTP using some other client from the machine you are trying to run this on? Does it work OK? It could be that you need to [define a proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx) for the FTPWebRequest to use. I'd also suggest using some form of protocol analyser like Fiddler or Wireshark to give you and idea of what is going on.

Comment: @Urvashi Are you sure it's just FTP and not SFTP?

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion 1 : EXPLICITLY set your timeout to infinite.

```
request.Timeout = -1;
```

Suggestion 2: Catch the more specific exception type WebException, and examine the WebExceptionStatus.

Suggestion 3: Turn on tracing for System.Net.

I've set the TraceLevel for two of the sources that aren't applicable in your situation.

[How to: Configure Network Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Http">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net "/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.WebSockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Off"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Off"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.WebSockets" value="Off"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```